# Firebase Realtime Database don't work in UAE

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing app with Firebase. From Firebase I'm using Auth and Realtime Database.

When app runs in Europe Auth and DB works good. But when in runs in UAE works only Auth, but not DB.

I know, that there are problems with Internet security in UAE, like filtering traffic.

My questing is how to escape it? Or just is this binded issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I asked firebase support and the told, that Firebase Realtime Database really has problems and those regions, but CloudFire Storage should work good

Comment: Have you try to use VPN ?